# MPLAB Object File Failed

Tags: c, mplab, pic32

I tried to build Microchip USB Stack files for PIC32 but MPLAB X IDE gave me error that it failed to build.

Following is the error while building.

*The system cannot find the path specified.
make[2]:*  [build/default/production/_ext/1961590870/usb_device.o] Error 1
make[1]:  *[.build-conf] Error 2*

Are Object files automatically made by Compiler? And how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the usb_device.c to your project from the MAL (C:\microchip_solutions_XX_XX_XXXX) folder. You can check out some of the examples in the MAL\USB\ folders. For each USB "type" (device/host/etc) you'll have to add different files into your project based on the application of the USB.

edit: right name of MAL folder on Windows.